# setText in CustomPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

This is my custom ViewPager adapter. I'm trying to set a title for each page to a TextView as a function of the position of the ViewPager. Why isn't this working?

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int[] image_resources = {
            android.R.color.transparent,
            R.drawable.image1,
    };
    private String[] title_resources = {
            "",
            "Title #1",
    };
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return (view == (RelativeLayout) o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageview.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        TextView title = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
        title.setText(title_resources[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.app.feed.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:114)
```

The error is definitely being thrown at the following line: `title.setText(title_resources[position]);`

Comment: post the code for R.layout.pager_item.xml

Comment: @j2emanue I've updated it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I got it working by adding the TextView to the pager_item.xml as correctly hinted at by j2emanue. Previously, I had my TextView in the layout of the page within which the ViewPager was located, which was incorrect.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```